# How to unset TTL of a HBase column family

Tags: hbase

Say I have these HBase tables, which are described in the HBase webui as:

```
test_foo      {NAME => 'test_foo', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'fam'}]}
test_bar      {NAME => 'test_bar', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'fam', TTL => '1000'}]}
```

how do I unset the TTL on the `test_bar` table?

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that the webui does not show default values.

If I use the hbase shell, I see (massaged output a bit for clarity here):

```
hbase(main)> describe 'test_foo'
{NAME => 'test_foo', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'fam', 
    BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3', 
    COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', 
    TTL => '2147483647', 
    BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}

hbase(main)> describe 'test_bar'
{NAME => 'test_bar', FAMILIES => [{NAME => 'fam', 
    BLOOMFILTER => 'NONE', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '3',
    COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0',
    TTL => '1000',
    BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}]}
```

So there is a TTL on the `test_foo` table as well of 2147483647 seconds (maximum value for 32bit signed int, corresponds to roughly 68 year), probably HBase's default TTL.

I set the TTL on the `test_bar` table to this maxint, e.g. as follows:

```
alter 'test_bar', {NAME => 'fam', TTL => '2147483647'}
```

Result: TTL attribute is not shown in webui anymore. #pieceofmind

Comment: TTL => '2147483647' this is indeed the default value. It's defined as a constant in source code.

Comment: hbase shell also accepts a more elegant
TTL => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HConstants::FOREVER